# Implementing action correctly

Tags: options

Hi I am implementing a core plugin plus add ons. There is a settings page and I would like to hook some validation routines for the addon plugin into the core plugin's validation function. However it's not working. Can you point me in the right direction?

Here's an excerpt of what I have:

```
    register_setting( 'myp_settings', 'myp_settings', 'myp_settings_validate' );

    function myp_settings_validate( $input ) {
      $options = get_option( 'myp_settings' );
      do_action( 'myp_settings_validate', $input, $options );
      return $options;
    }
```

The above is in the core plugin's code, while the below is in the addon plugin:

```
add_action( 'myp_settings_validate', 'myp_settings_et_validate', '', 2 );

function myp_settings_et_validate( $input, $options ) {

    if ( ! isset( $input['excerpt_enable'] ) || $input['excerpt_enable'] != '1' )
    $options['excerpt_enable'] = 0;
    else
    $options['excerpt_enable'] = 1;

    if ( ! isset( $input['thumbnail_enable'] ) || $input['thumbnail_enable'] != '1' )
    $options['thumbnail_enable'] = 0;
    else
    $options['thumbnail_enable'] = 1;

    return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_action()` does not *use* a returned value. It works more like the `onload` event in JavaScript: You cannot undo the load. To change a value you need *filters*.

If you want to change the option content, hook into `pre_update_option_{$option_name}` very late (with a high priority parameter):

```
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_myp_settings', 'myp_settings_et_validate', 100, 3 );

function myp_settings_et_validate( $option, $newvalue, $oldvalue )
{
    # do something awesome and return a value
}
```